# I can edit and save the powerapp in the solution but can not run/play in the sandbox environment

Tags: powerapps-canvas

Hi I need to work on Power App part of Solution in the Sandbox environment. I can edit and save the app, however when I play I get the error message for request access below. I have Microsoft Power Apps and Logic Flows license assigned. Can someone help what i am missing ? Thanks

[image]